# Entity cannot be found error in Dynamics 365 for Outlook App

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics365-app-outlook

We receive the following error in the Dynamics 365 for Outlook App:

> The entity "{0}" cannot be found. Specify a valid query, and try
>   again.

This appears to be associated with custom code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was happening because of a call to `Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords`. It appears as though in the full web client if you pass in the entity set name (ex. 'accounts') instead of the entity logical name as documented (ex. 'account') as the first parameter, then the web client just passes it through as it's not found in the `ENTITY_SET_NAMES` constant.

However, in the app, there is no `ENTITY_SET_NAMES` and so my guess is a metadata call is being made on demand to lookup the entity set name and failing because we were passing the set name instead of the logical name.

This appears to have been corrected by switching to the logical name.

Comment: I noticed this last week in an UCI app.